# how to solve this system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve this system
\begin{align*}\tag{*}
x'(s)=x^2(s)+y(s),
y'(s)=x(s)y(s)
\end{align*}
with initial conditions $$x(0)=t, y(0)=t,$$
where $t\not=0.$

With the help of Maple, the solution is

$$ x \left( s \right) ={\frac {2\,st+2\,t}{-{s}^{2}t-2\,st+2}}, ~y \left( s \right) =2\,{\frac {t}{-{s}^{2}t-2\,st+2}}. $$

But I want to know the details of the whole process of solution.

I have tried to convert this system into a single ODE $$x''(s)=3x(s)x'(s)-x^3(s). \tag{**}$$
But this ODE is semilinear, which is beyond my capability to solve. Then I tried to deduced the order by transformation $$p=x'(s),~~ p\frac{dp}{dx}=x''(s),$$ which simplified $(**)$ to 
$$\frac{dp}{dx}=3x-\frac{x^3}{p},\tag{***}$$
which is also difficult for me to solve.

Can anyone help me to solve $(*)$ , $(**)$ or $(***)$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide the two equations. You get
$${dx\over dy}={x\over y}+{1\over x}.$$
Multiply by $x$ and set $x^2=u$. You get
$${1\over 2}{du\over dy}={u\over y}+1,$$
a linear equation.

Comment: Of course, there is always the possibility that you are dividing by zero :(

Comment: The separate discussion of this special case is, as we usually say, left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Michael Renardy: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, after multiplying by $x$ won't you get ${x{dx\over dy}}={{x^2}\over y}+1$?  How does the LHS convert to what you have in your second equation after setting $x^2 = u$?

Comment: @MattPhillips by differentiating $x^2=u$ by $y$ you get $2x\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{du}{dy}$ this is part of standard u-substitution